# Can an Angular Route apply a url parameter?

Tags: angular

I am looking for a way to convert the last part of a route path into a query param... I was hoping I could do:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'xyz/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./some.module').then(m => m.SomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'xyz/:id/abc',
    redirectTo: 'xyz/:id?abc=true',
  },
]
```

But it appears the `?abc=true` does not get added.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you can add a custom guard with redirect to do that. it seems there is no such out of the box solution